# VLC: undefined symbol

Tags: vlc

Whenever I try to run VLC, I get the following error:

```
vlc: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/libvlc.so.5: undefined symbol: vlc_object_hold
```

I've tried uninstalling it and reinstalling it (as well as orphaned dependencies), but that only gives me this similar error:

```
/usr/lib/vlc/vlc-cache-gen: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/libvlc.so.5: undefined symbol: vlc_object_hold
```

I have only tried installing VLC from my distro's repos. I have not tried any third-party repos, nor have I tried compiling from source. I have an old version (3.0.11-1-x86) in the form of an AppImage, which works fine, but I'd like to fix this problem instead of working around it. Any ideas?

Arch GNU/Linux, x86_64. VLC 3.0.16-7 was the newest version in the repos at the time of writing.

Comment: Is the second error you report following the command : /usr/lib/vlc/vlc-cache-gen /usr/lib/vlc/plugins ? If not, try firing this command under console. And BTW, "orphaned deps" ?? You mean you have *orphaned deps* on your system ?

Comment: By orphaned dependencies, I mean packages that were installed just so that VLC could run. That said, I don't understand your first question, but I tried the "vlc-cache-gen" command anyway. Same error as reinstalling VLC.